# Load external script dynamic, and access it, so I can trigger its domready function

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am trying to load the Zopim chat client. Normally it is included with a document write action. This causes it to be loaded before the domReady function is triggered, as it needs this to start itself.

I want to load it later, and this works by using prototype (framework determined by Magento) to create a new script element and attaching it to the head. The script is loaded perfectly, but the domReady doesn't fire, so the script is never started.

*The script is a nameless class, by this I mean that all its functions are encapsulated in {}*
UPDATE: Sorry, I got it wrong, it is as self invoking function, the same syntax as the first answer suggest.
(function C(){
})();

This function call when run sets up listening events for the domReady event under various browsers and then waits. When the domready event fires, it calls a function (that is within the self-invoked function) that starts everything. What I need, is a way to access this function somehow.
END UPDATE

Within that is a function named C.

How can I call this function directly?

Or put another way, how can I start an external javascript file that depends on domready going off, when that event doesn't happen?

Can I load an external javascript file into a variable, so I can name the class?
Can I access the nameless class {} somehow maybe via the script tag?
Is there a way to alter the external file/javascript so I can have it look for another event, one that I can trigger?

About the only solution I can think of at the moment is to create a iframe and load the script in that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire it after loading it asynchronously after the domready is already fired, you can do this:

Make your function **C** a self invoking function by:

```
(function C(){
})();
```

With this approach you would be changing the external script though.

Comment: This wouldn't be ideal, the external script does not belong to me, and the entire script is it self a self invoking function as you described, and I need to call a function within that, or trigger domready somehow.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "nameless class", can you provide a simple example of what the javascript looks like?

Also, RE the previous comment, making a self-invoking function does NOT mean it will wait for anything, it has nothing to do with DOM ready.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can load it later and get the function to execute without modifying the script.

The script is designed in a way to trigger on domready. When you include it later by injecting via the <script> tag, domready has already triggered. Triggering domready again is equivalent to injecting the script beforehand using document.write.

The other option is to load the external JS into a variable somehow. I am not aware of such techniques. Since script has an anonymous object, you also don't get a handle to invoke a function on the object.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am going to try loading it in an iframe instead. That should give me both the choice when to load it and still get a domready event on it.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You may trigger the event programmatically, for example:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('DOMContentLoaded'));
```

See [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

But note that this solution can be tricky to make it work correctly, cause when you trigger the event, some event handlers that have registered to the event will trigger a second time. And this causes problems like page not working as expected or an infinite loop (event registering, handler call, event registering, handler call indefinitely).

So you would need a solution to make sure that the different scripts that registered to the `DOMContentLoaded` event have their handlers only called 1 time exactly.